# HtmlUnit - Executing a button with javascript

Tags: javascript, button, click, htmlunit

I want to extract some information from a website. In order to do this I use HtmlUnit to simulate some clicks.

The website is : http://www.sixt.com/car-rental/

I want to set a specific value into the textfield i.e "70629" and click the button below. The button on the site executes some javascript.

I've tried everything out and read different posts (also on stackoverflow) but nothing seems to work :/

My code so far:

```
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_24);
    webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

    HtmlPage page;
    try {
        page = webClient.getPage(SIXT_ADDRESS);

        //checking a checkbox
        HtmlInput checkbox0 = (HtmlInput) page.getElementById("sx-branch-search-panel-option_F");
        checkbox0.click();

        //setting input for textfield
        HtmlTextInput textField1 = (HtmlTextInput) page.getElementById("i-mf__inputfield");
        textField1.setValueAttribute("70629");

        //load new page through button click
        HtmlElement theElement2 = (HtmlElement) page.getElementById("submit_button");
        page = theElement2.click();

        System.out.println(page.asText());
```

Why does the output still shows the content from the website above and not the new page? (textfield value and checkbox are set!).

I've noticed that

```
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);
```

will remove the textfield value ("70629") in the output.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: And why does this code work for other sites?

Comment: verify if there is some onclick, onblur events on those inputs. You can simulate it on htmlUnit, like textField1.focus(); textField1.value(...); textField1.blur().. Also try to fire 'submit' event and not clicking on button.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Yes. If I remember correctly we chose another approach and send a simple http request to the form of the appropriate website.